# How to test an element with protractor that has no id or class?

Tags: html, css, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I am new to protractor and am trying to test various elements within the code (code that I did not write).

here is an example of some of the code:

```
<ul class="primary_menu"> <li class=""> <a href="http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;localhost&#x3a;8080&#x2f;web&#x2f;aaaa_customer&#x2f;home" > Home</a> </li>
```

as can be seen above this element does not have an ID and the class is empty. therefore how do I access this?
below is some code that I wrote to access an element that had an ID:

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('header-search-link')).click();
```

I have also tried to access an element by.css but it did not work for the problem above.

any help would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access the `Home` link, simply get it by [*partial link text*](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.partialLinkText):

```
element(by.partialLinkText('Home'));
```

Or, you can use a [*CSS selector*](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css):

```
element.all(by.css('ul.primary_menu > li > a')).first();
```

Comment: ok this makes sense, but then how do i add the click function?? currently when i add it after first like so: `.first().click();`, it says no function click of undefined

Comment: quick question, how do you access the second element?? .second() appears not to work?

Comment: is there anyway I can private message you about stuff? drop me a mail at `mikesjones1987@gmail.com` maybe

Answer (score 0):

According to http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/locators#finding-sub-elements you can chain locators to find an element:

```
element(by.css('.primary_menu')).element(by.tagName('li'));
```

or

```
element(by.css('.primary_menu li'));
```

(untested, I never worked with Protractor)

Comment: Ok, so how is this working?  I want to access the first element in the second list on the page.
As far as I can tell yours is accessing the first element within the first 'li'? how do you specify which ul to hit and which li within that to hit? if you see what i mean

Comment: With `get()` you can access a specific element. If you want the first `li` in the second `ul` use (the numbering starts with 0) `element(by.css('.primary_menu')).get(1).element(by.tagName('li')).get(0);`

Comment: object object has no method 'get'?
this is my exact line: `browser.driver.findElement(by.css('primary_menu')).get(1).element(by.tagName('ul')).get(0).click();`